# Show a Widget when an alarm fires in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Is it possible to show a widget when an alarm fires in flutter? My use case is, I set an alarm every hour to check for some calendar events and would like to show a widget which would describe the event in a widget.

Code:
I set Alarm in main() like this

```
await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), 1, performNotificationService);
```

and in performNotificationService I would like to show a widget even if the application is in background/killed. I tried to rerun the app with:

```
void performNotificationService() {
    runApp(new ShowNewNotification());
}
```

where ShowNewNotification is one more stateless widget in main.dart.

Thanks,
Adarsha HD